# How to customize the git commit-msg hook?

Tags: perl, git

How can you validate the comment in the commit message dialog box.
For example, the comment may be CSCRM12345678.

Answer (score 3):

use `prepare-commit-msg` githooks. Try to find $GIT_DIR/hooks/*